# Would it be wrong if "file_exists" was designed to return a path instead of TRUE?

Tags: php, language-design

The [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists) function returns TRUE on success but I think it would be more useful if instead of just TRUE, it returned the value of the passed `$filename`. Am I wrong to think that?

If the function was designed like that, we would be able to use:

```
$file = file_exists("dir/file.ext");

if($file)
{
    // do something
}
```

... instead of the more complicated:

```
$file = "dir/file.ext";

$success = file_exists("dir/file.ext");

if($success)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why that would be an improvement. Consider that:

1. In practice you will put the `file_exists` call inside the condition, thus there will be no extra `$success` variable
2. The name `file_exists` predisposes the reader of the code that the function will return a yes/no answer (boolean value)

So in conclusion, I think that it would be a bad idea to change nothing but the type of the return value.

Comment: Good points, still, would it be of any harm if it returned the passed file path instead of TRUE?

Comment: @Emanuil: It depends on what it would return if the file did *not* exist. I can't *think* of an example that would cause harm right now (mainly because PHP is loosely typed), but I 'm sure there are programmers who don't know what `file_exists` does exactly and would be quite happy to invent ways to break it.

Answer (score 4):

file_exists? is basically a yes or no question, so it gives a yes or no (boolean) answer.

Does the file exist? "Yes", it exists.

So it's aptly named for what it does

Answer (score 3):

That would just make no sense. It could also return the file permissions, the file size, the last modified date, and still it would make as much sense as the filename. It is nothing but a check that gives a Boolean value, and you can make decisions based on it.

By the way, I don't get your examples, what could be easier than:

```
$file = "dir/file.ext";
if(file_exists($file))
{
    // do something with $file
}
```

Or if you really need the return value later, you could do:

```
$file = "dir/file.ext";
if($success=file_exists($file))
{
    // do something with $file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, nothing really prevents you from writing this function:

```
function get_filename_if_exists($fname) {
    return (file_exists($fname) ? $fname : FALSE );
}
```

It is IMHO problematic as it has multiple return types, and doesn't give you any more information than you'd get from `file_exists()` - and therefore worse than pointless; but it is possible to shoot yourself in the foot like this, if you really want.

(this behavior is unlikely to get retrofitted into `file_exists()`, for the reasons stated here and in the other answers)

Answer (score 1):

Then what would be the use of [fopen](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fopen.php)?

```
$res = fopen("my/path.txt");
if ($res===FALSE) {
  // File does not exists or an error while opening
}
```

If you specifically want to know whether a file exists then the file_exists function does what it is supposed to do.

```
if (FALSE===file_exists("my/path.txt")) {
  // Stop here, 
}
```